# ios - view position inside cell tableview changes only after scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, cell

I have a tablewiew using ios 8.0+, i added a checkbox to each cell - on iphone 5 works great, but when testing on iphone 6 - the checkbox is in the right position only after scrolling...
(the second picture is after scrolling)

****cant add photos yet:) so what i actually see at first load is that the checkbox get some rightpadding -> after I scroll some of the checkboxes moves to the right - where they should be
Code below
Thank you!

```
CGFloat y =self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y;
tableData = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, y+10, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - y -30 - nextButton.frame.size.height -10) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableData.dataSource = self;
tableData.delegate = self;



[self.view addSubview:tableData];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  }
   else
    {
        CTCheckbox *check =  [cell.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
        [check removeFromSuperview];
    }






CTCheckbox *checkbox;

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
checkbox = [[CTCheckbox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-60, cell.frame.size.height/2-10, 50, 20.0)];
checkbox.alpha = 0.7;
[checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
checkbox.tag = indexPath.row;
[checkbox setColor:[BlendedColors pink] forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Expertise label
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0 ];
cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;

cell.textLabel.text = [experties objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [BlendedColors black];
[cell addSubview:checkbox];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;


if([[selectedCheckBox objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"YES"])
{
    checkbox.checked = YES;
}
else{
    checkbox.checked = NO;
}


//cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - First cell width is always 320

added 3 lines

```
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //Fix Bug - first cell view is always 320 - now its dynamic(cell width = device width)
        CGRect cellFrame = cell.frame;
        cellFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
        cell.frame = cellFrame;


  }
```